# NumberFormat showing wrong decimal mark format for currencies for some locales

Tags: java, localization

For some locales like es-CO, I get the numberformat Decimal mark for currency as incorrect:

```
 NumberFormat numberFormat =
 NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("es", "CO"));
 numberFormat.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("COP"));

 String currencyString = numberFormat.format(164900.12);
 System.out.println(currencyString);
```

for this I am getting the result as 164.900,21 whereas when I check in sites like: http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert
I get it other way round i.e 164,900.21
Is this an issue with NumberFormat class or am I doing anything wrong.

Comment: Try with new Locale("es_CO"). For more info http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html

Comment: The Danes use the comma as the decimal separator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark

Comment: As per this link https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSS28S_8.1.0/XFDL/i_xfdl_r_formats_es_CO.html and http://www.localeplanet.com/java/es-CO/index.html what you are getting is correct

Answer (score 0):

Please check the constructor of Locale class it is excepting the language first and then the country code

```
 public Locale(String language, String country) {
    this(language, country, "");
 }
```

Change your code like this you will get output like this "COP 164,900.12"

```
  NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale(
                "CO", "es"));
```

Comment: I have added language first only. es for spanish and CO is for columbia.